# Sort WooCommerce categories automatically into friendly-looking tree

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, sort

have a problem, I've uploaded bunch of products into WooCommerce store via XML file. Something like 45,000 products and xml didn't had certain category for every product, instead it had meta tag with some short description similar to a name of category like "Floor mirror", "Wall mirror", "Mirror with shelf".
So now i have like 500-700 categories. Is there a way to maybe categories all of this automatically into a much smaller tree of categories? Maybe like sort them by words in the names? Like make all caterogies with word mirrors in the name into subcategories and than put into one big category called "Mirrors".

Is there a way to do that? Because sorting all this by hand using wordpress admin panel is going to take forever...
Thanks in advance for the help.